# How to return HttpResponseException with error specificaton (invalid username or invalid password) to the frontend?

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

How do i return Bad Request exception with text like "Invalid username" to frontend in ApiController.
My code:

```
public class FrontEndController : ApiController
    {
        public string Test(string value)
        {
            if(!isValid(value))
               //how do i throw exception with its code (400 in this case) and message ("Invalid username")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your method return type to `HttpResponseMessage` and use the built in API functionality to return the error message you'd like.

```
public class FrontEndController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Test(string value)
        {
            if(!isValid(value))
              {
                 //Generate error response here
                 return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Username");
              }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HttpException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx)  and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bazc3hww(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor

```
throw new HttpException(400, "Invalid username")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a BadRequest method on ApiController:

```
return BadRequest("Invalid username");
```

This creates an ErrorMessageResult (400 Bad Request) with the specified error message.

Comment: What should the method return? I can't get it to work.

Comment: It might be that this method is only in asp.net core. try add 'new'; `return new BadRequest("Invalid username");`